# Filtering list in python based on condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I have following implementation where CSV file is converted into one row numpy array:

```
results = []
with open(file2) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) 
# change contents to floats
    for row in reader: # each row is a list
        results.append(row)
        print(numpy.percentile(results, perc, axis = None))
        perc_value = numpy.percentile(results, perc, axis = None)
```

Now the idea is that based on percentile provided by user that returns certain value - let's say 100 I want to remove all entries from array that are below 100.

```
so example results is [1, 50, 200, 500, 1000, 2000]
perc_value = 100
end result should be [200, 500, 1000, 2000]
```

i tried multiple attempts but either I recieve an error of boolean for numpy or that the condition cannot be applied for the list, any ideas?

I tried following:

```
       for i in range (len(results)):
           if results[i] > perc_value: results.pop(i)
       print (results)
```

Error msg:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried and the error message?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49259210/edit) the question and paste your properly formatted code there.

Comment: done, edited, thanks!

Comment: Try `results[numpy.where(result > perc_value)]`

Comment: getting following type error with that TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: You filter processing data as soon as possible to skip lengthy imports of useless data. The cvs file is for backup so you'll always have the raw data at hand anyway.... if some wacky manager decides to do a zillion-th time check on outdated data.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes people think to complex... keep it simple and select earlier in the process...

Row = string.

```
# arbitrary taken selector values and char.
key      = 100 
position = 4
splitter = '.'

for row in reader: # row as a string.

    # preprocess input
    string_row = str(row)
    row_data = string_row.split (splitter)

    if int(row_data[position]) == key: # selection is done here

        results.append(row)
        print(numpy.percentile(results, perc, axis = None))
        perc_value = numpy.percentile(results, perc, axis = None)
```

Row = list with variables:

```
# arbitrary taken selector values and char.
key      = 100 
position = 4
splitter = '.'

for row in reader: # each row is a list

    if int(row[position]) == key: # selection is done here

        results.append(row)
        print(numpy.percentile(results, perc, axis = None))
        perc_value = numpy.percentile(results, perc, axis = None)
```

Comment: Will check but I am not sure if I get your code, the idea here is to calculate percentile value (e.g. 100) based on percentile % inputted by the user (%25) from the same large list and then manipulate same list by removing values below percentile value

Comment: the value I took at key is arbitrary.. it can be a small function if you need to calculate the real value... or range (returning two selector values). Then in the latter case its selector will be `if int(row[position]) in range(value1, value2):`